# Use ArgumentCaptor outside of .verify()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have an entity which is not used as an argument in a .verify(), but only an attribute of that entity. However, I would like to capture the entity to later use assertEquals to verify another attribute of that entity. Is this possible if the entity is not used in the .verify() at all?

The thing I found out is that I can only capture an argument if I use it with .when() or .verify(). Neither makes sense in itself though, because the only class in which I use or return the entity directly as a parameter is the class I also want to test. So I use @Autowired for them and not @MockBean for example. If I try to include the entity inside the .verify() somehow, it gives a NullPointerException

```
ArgumentCaptor<Entity> entityArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Entity.class);

Mockito.verify(reportMock, Mockito.times(1)).doIt(Mockito.eq(entityArgumentCaptor.capture().getIdentifier()), Mockito.eq(null)); //not working
Entity entityArguments = entityArgumentCaptor.getValue();
assertEquals(entityState.completed, entityArguments.getState());
```

Comment: You know what they say: Code is worth a 1000 descriptions of code. Can you please include: 1) the types used in your examples 2) the signature of `doIt` 3) the code calling this method

Answer (score 1):

You want to capture your entity, then assert its property:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Entity> entityArgumentCaptor
    = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Entity.class);
Mockito.verify(reportMock)
    .doIt(Mockito.eq(entityArgumentCaptor.capture()), Mockito.isNull());
Entity entityArguments = entityArgumentCaptor.getValue();
assertEquals(
    entityState.completed,
    entityArguments.getIdentifier().getState());
```

Comment: That wont work, because .doIt() takes a String (here called identifier) as first parameter, not an entity

Comment: @FabianLüdicke I'm not sure I understand. If the first parameter is a String, then you need an `ArgumentCaptor<String>` (or simply use `Mockito.eq` in the verify call). Where/how does the entity come into play?

Comment: My bad. Let me try to clarify it. I am testing a method called activity.doIt. This activity.doIt has the same identifier as parameter as the reportMock.doIt. Identifier is a attribute of my entity, just like state. In activity.doIt i am calling a reportMock.doIt. Thats what i am checking with .verify(). The activity.doIt also changes the attribute state of my entity. Thats what i need to check too. How? I cant capture the Entity because i only have its identifier as parameter.

Comment: @FabianLüdicke [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75426597/edit) to include the calling code. Trying to describe code is futile, just show the (da\*\*) code. If you don't have an entity, you cannot capture it (but without seeing code, nobody can give a definitive answer.